# R2dbc postgresql data loss issue

Tags: postgresql, reactive-programming, reactive, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I have a reactive kafka consumer which read the data and saves the data into postgresql db using reactive drivers. Sometimes some data gets missed to save in the database , without any error . However, I could see the data read by my kafka consumer in logs.

This can be the reactive programming which is causing data loss or some issue with reactive drivers, because no connection errors or exceptions could be seen in logs.
Any help would be appreciated a lot.